# General question regarding possibilities of Flutter homescreen widgets

Tags: flutter, animation, widget, homescreen

I'm new to app development and had a brief look into Flutter (looks cool!).
I even had a first idea for a homescreen widget.
To what I've read so far, it's not that straight-forward, but my question is:
Are there any limitations regarding fancy animations with Flutter for homescreen widgets?
I mean is homescreen widget animation possible with Flutter or do I really need native approaches (like Kotlin) for this?
Thanks for your feedback!

(I haven't tried anything practical yet, thus the general question first.)

Comment: What type of animations do you have in mind?

Comment: @Texv, basically, the ones provided there:
[link](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_animate/latest/)

Comment: Since you've linked to a Flutter package, the answer is yes—it's possible to make all those animations in Flutter, you can just use that package :)

Comment: @nate-thegrate But will these effects also work in/for the homescreen widget?
According to [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/flutter-home-screen-widgets) it says "...you can't directly draw the UI of a Home Screen widget using the Flutter framework." So I assume(d) this includes animations as well...

Comment: Ah—I'm so used to "Widget" meaning a Dart object that I totally missed that you were referring to Android home screen widgets. Yeah, I'm not sure about those… I'll upvote this question for visibility.